# How to create sub categories of the sub categories

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a store, with categories. What I want to achieve:

```
Main category
   sub category
       sub category of the sub category
another main one
```

At the moment I have a table structure like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `main_category` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sub_category` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `categories`
--

INSERT INTO `categories` (`category_id`, `main_category`, `sub_category`, `category_date`) VALUES
(1, 'Electronics', 'Laptops', '2016-02-21 13:49:14'),
--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--
```

I want to create sub categories so the user can click the main category which whill show all sub categories or click the sub category which will show the sub categories of the sub category, or click the sub sub category.

In my product table, I cam using the category id so it can be joined n the category, here's my php:

```
public static function category_form()
{
    echo '<select name="categories" class="form-control col-sm-12">';
    echo '<option>'.System::translate('Choose an option').'</option>';

        $i = 0;
        $mainCatName = '';
        foreach(SELF::categories() as $category): 
            if($category->main_category != $mainCatName) {
                $mainCatName = $category->main_category;
                if($i = 0) { 
                    echo '<optgroup label="'.$category->main_category.'">';
                } else {
                    echo '';
                    echo '<optgroup label="'.$category->main_category.'">';
                }
            }

            echo '<option value="'.System::escape($category->sub_category).'">'.System::escape($category->sub_category).'</option>'; 
            $i++;
            endforeach;
    echo '</select>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a single equal sign `==` or `===` to compare not a signle `=` , it sets $i value as `0` in every iteration, change it to this:

```
if($i == 0) {
```